# Horizontally concatenate column vectors that typed in multiple line

Tags: matlab

I have two matrix a ,b :

```
a = [ 1 2 3
      4 5 6 ]

b = [ 7 8 
      9 10 ]
```

I want to create a matrix c as shown below:

```
c = [ 1 2 3 7 8
      4 5 6 9 10 ]
```

but I want type this in multiple line a shown below, like this:

```
c = [ a(:,:),
      b(:,:) ]
```

because that i want arranging to multiple line, i dont want use this syntax in single line:

```
c = [a(:,:) b(:,:)]
```

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Three dots](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014a/matlab/matlab_prog/continue-long-statements-on-multiple-lines.html) are your friend

```
c = [ a(:,:), ...
      b(:,:) ]
```